# how to run batch file on remote machines shared folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, remote-access

I have 2 PC's on my LAN, PC1 and PC2.

PC2 has a Shared Folder with read & write access; \\PC2\Shared_Folder\

I have a Batch File on PC1:- C:\>batch.bat

I want to execute the batch file using Command Prompt from PC1 on remote PC2.

Note: Cannot Install any Software on any of the PC's and only windows file sharing is on between the PC's.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you mean you want to execute your batch file with current directory as `\\PC2\Shared_Folder` ? Or execute on PC2 directly?

Comment: Priority is to execute on PC2 Directly.

Comment: If you wish to execute something on PC2, but called from PC1, then you'll have to install something implicitly on PC2 that will allow you to do so via a well defined calling interface from PC1. Or just remote desktop on to PC2 and do it from there.

Comment: The cynic in me says this is "I want to hack my roommate's computer via their shared folder". Regardless, "how do I manage Windows" is off topic for StackOverflow, and might be a better fit for superuser.com. Unless it's actually *the batch file code* which has problems. Either way, you should totally *try* solving your problem, and post what you've tried. See the "how to ask" guides. (NB. Computers aren't magic, you can't arbitrarily restrict the conditions and still do everything. You might do it with DCOM, WMI, VBscript, PSExec, but if all you allow is batch file, it might be impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common ways to do this is to use the [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) tool from Windows Sysinternals:

```
PC1 Prompt> psexec \\PC2 \\PC1\Shared_Folder\Batch.cmd
```

Note:  What this hides from you is it *does* install a program on PC2.  It does so automatically, but it still requires sufficient access on the target machine to access `\\PC2\ADMIN$`

Comment: Want to execute the batch from PC1.
PC1 Prompt>

Comment: Ok, swapped PC1 and PC2

Comment: Is there any way around  without using psexec ( as cannot install psexec on any of the PC's )

Comment: No.  Your question asked different:  "How can I instruct a remote PC to run a program without any user interaction or program to launch it for me?"  Any answer to the question is a security problem.

Comment: I can work around with PSEXEC from PC1
Any Pre-Requirement on PC2 fo this ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, you'll need access to `\\PC2\ADMIN$`, which generally means you need a user account with sufficient permissions to install a service on it, since that's what PsExec does under the covers:  It installs a service on the remote machine to handle the requests for you.